# Submitting dropdown menu forms with python?

Tags: python, html, forms, python-requests

I'm trying to submit a form in Python and scrape the HTML from the page it returns. The form currently looks like this:

```
<form name="valform">
<p><table><tbody><tr><td>
  <select name="param1" size="1">
    <option value></option>
    <option value="ACFM">ACFM</option>
    <option value="ANBE">ANBE</option>
    <option value="ANTH">ANTH</option>
    ...
    <option value="WMST">WMST</option>
  </select>
</td></tr></tbody></table></p>

<p>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</p>
</form>
```

I'm trying to select one of the options and submit the form with the input button below. I've been using [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) but the only things I can find on that are related to submitting text in forms, not selecting options.

How can I do this with requests? Or do I need to use some other Python library?

Answer (score 1):

In a POST request, all the data is always submitted in text form only, be it text fields, dropdowns or others (except file uploads, of course). Simply monitor the Network tab of Google Chrome Developer Console to find out what all data is being submitted in the post request.